# How to create a validation rule so that only two users A and B can change values from a lookup picklist?

Tags: formula-field

I need to create a validation rule on two lookup fields on same custom object so that only two users A and B can change values on that field,rest other users cannot change values.

Kindly help!!

I tried the syntax i.e .AND ( ISCHANGED( Owner_Proposal__c ), $User.Username ="andrew@abc.com"<> "Owner_Proposal__c ", $User.Username="elan@dfc.com"<> "Owner_Proposal__c ") but I get a syntax error.

Please let me know the reason for syntax error.

Need your help!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the below formula to create your validation rule.

AND( ISCHANGED (Owner_Proposal__c ) ,  OR( (LastModifiedBy.Username <> 'andrew@abc.com') , (LastModifiedBy.Username <> 'elan@dfc.com')) )

Hope this helps.

Thanks!

Comment: Thanks a lot Ruchika. It worked perfectly. Actually I am new to salesforce.Can you provide me some links so that I can learn how to use formulaes.

Comment: If I need to add another field owner close how can I add in the existing syntax

Comment: what validation exactly you want to put on the owner close ? Can you explain bit briefly what you want to do in it ?

Comment: Hi Ruchika,I want to add both fields under same syntax. ie. I want to add owner_close_c field under same syntax .Is it possible or new need to create a workflow inorder to use both syntax in one formulae

Comment: Try doing this:

AND( OR(ISCHANGED (Owner_Proposal__c ) , ISCHANGED (owner_close_c) ), OR( (LastModifiedBy.Username <> 'andrew@abc.com') , (LastModifiedBy.Username <> 'elan@dfc.com')) )

Comment: Please mark my answer as best answer if this solves your problem. Thanks!

Comment: Can I add on gmail or is there any option to add you, because i am new in salesforce and would require your help.Thanks

Comment: You can ask your doubts in my discussion room named "Salesforce Doubts" in the "CHAT" option.

Comment: Thanks Ruchika, I would for sure require your help in salesforce.Thanks a lot!!

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
AND ( ISCHANGED(Owner_Proposal__c), 
      OR(
          $User.Username <> "andrew@abc.com",
          $User.Username <> "elan@dfc.com"
        )
    )
```

If you read it from beginning, that mean - if some field is changed **and** user name is not equal to one **or** not equal to another one - show error.

In your formula in can not understand what is this:

```
$User.Username ="andrew@abc.com"<> "Owner_Proposal__c "
```

Because result of first part is boolean (true or false, $User.Username is equal or not equal to "andrew@abc.com"), as well as last argument is string type. It can not compare boolean result with string, so it shows syntax error.

Here you can find examples of validation rules:
https://help.salesforce.com/HTViewHelpDoc?id=fields_useful_field_validation_formulas.htm&language=en_US

Answer (score 0):

why you want validation rule you set field level security where those 2 user profile can only have access to the field not other. Setup > Build> create> open the object and click on the filed you want to hide from other users> click on set-field-level security > and select the profile.

Comment: Hi Anu, The other users can edit the values but they cannot change the values,other users while entering values after saving cannot change values while these two users can change values